# Problems with Android Bluetooth Server and Client

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, client, server

I have a couple problems regarding creating a bluetooth server and client for a multiplayer game I'm making.
The first problem I have is searching for devices. Google provides following code:

```
// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
};
// Register the BroadcastReceiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
```

But I can't find where mArrayAdapter is defined or how it should look like.
Second question I have is, when I have a server running on my device, do I have to connect to it also, or does only the other phone have to connect and my server acts as a client and a server?

Third question I have is how to connect to the server. Again, google provides this code:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

How do I create and use this class, and what variable should I pass for `BluetoothDevice device` in the constructor?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see from `mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());` that a String is added. So it will be defined as:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.bluetooth_device_name);
```

Where did you get your code from? The complete code you can find in DeviceListActivity.java of the BluetoothChat example app which comes with the SDk for many versions again and again.

For your second question: One app on a device makes the device visible. The other app on the other device scanns for neighbouring devices and tries to connect. Then both devices have to agree.

I advise you to do the BluetoothChat app from tne examples first. It works out of the box.

Comment: Thank you. I got that code from the android documentation, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). What is bluetooth_device_name?

Comment: That is -as usual- the name of a layout file used in the DeviceListActivity.

Comment: Is there any premade layout file, like android uses in the device settings and so on?

Comment: Sorry for asking, didn't know that makes you angry!